# Java: error - non-static variable scan cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, non-static

I have this **error**:

`non-static variable scan cannot be referenced from a static context`

---

Question has been improved.

1) Posted a code instead of a pic.

2) Improved a formatting and question itself.

Comment: Make sure to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) while your upcoming question ban lasts.

Comment: You have to post your code here, not a picture.

Comment: @baao Thanks for note. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to declare the class variables as static. So you will have:

```
static char val;
static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Awaa!